# Webkit callAsyncJavaScript not waitng for async await function call in SwiftUI

Tags: javascript, ios, swift, webkit, indexeddb

I am using WebKit in SwiftUI to update my indexedDB, but for some reason, the *callAsyncJavaScript* function of the webkit module is not waiting for the await response, can someone help? What changes or methods should I implement for the correct functionality of this task? I am new to SwiftUI and want to access the indexedDB.

Here is the sample code for reference.

**swiftcode.swift** -

```
import SwiftUI
import WebKit

struct IndexedDBView: UIViewRepresentable {
    var jsCode: String

    class Coordinator: NSObject, WKNavigationDelegate {
        var webView: WKWebView?
        var jsCode: String

        init(jsCode: String) {
            self.jsCode = jsCode
        }

        func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!) {
            self.webView = webView
            webView.callAsyncJavaScript(jsCode, in: nil, in: .page) { result in
                switch result {
                case let .failure(error):
                    debugPrint("failure \(error)")
                case let .success(result):
                    print(result)
                }
            }
        }
    }

    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        return Coordinator(jsCode: jsCode)
    }

    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> WKWebView {
        let webViewConfiguration = WKWebViewConfiguration()
        let webView = WKWebView(frame: .zero, configuration: webViewConfiguration)
        webView.navigationDelegate = context.coordinator
        return webView
    }

    func updateUIView(_ uiView: WKWebView, context: Context) {
        if let htmlPath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "abcd", ofType: "html") {
            let htmlURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: htmlPath)
            uiView.loadFileURL(htmlURL, allowingReadAccessTo: htmlURL)
        }
    }
}
```

**abcd.html -**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.21/lodash.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/crypto-js@3.1.9-1/crypto-js.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/idb@8/build/umd.js"></script>
    <script src="yourScript.js"></script>
    <script src="sample.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="updateMe">Initial content</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**sample.js -**

```
const getKeyForEncryptAndDecrypt = (userId) => {
    if (userId) {
        let first = '';
        let second = '';
        for (let index = 0; index < userId.length; index += 2) {
          first += userId[index];
          second = userId[index + 1] + second;
        }
        const key = first + second;
        return key;
      }
      return '';
};

    const handleSetPassAndTicketWithDB = async () => {
        var decryptkey = getKeyForEncryptAndDecrypt('9953425561');
        var myIndexDB = IndexDB(objectStoreKeys.myPassHistory);
        let pass = await myIndexDB.get('twqwa', decryptkey);
        var divElement = document.getElementById('updateMe');
        if (divElement) {
            divElement.innerHTML = 'IndexedDB updated with key: ' + JSON.stringify(pass);
        }
        return pass;
    };
```

And Here is how I am calling the IndexedDBView in my swiftui code -

```
IndexedDBView(jsCode: "handleSetPassAndTicketWithDB();")
```

On the screen, I am getting pass as "undefined".

The IndexDB function contains an object of async-await functions, and is written in *yourscript.js* file.

Answer (score 0):

- The handleSetPassAndTicketWithDB function is defined in the sample.js file, which is loaded in the abcd.html file. However, when you call this function from SwiftUI using webView.callAsyncJavaScript(jsCode, in: nil, in: .page), the function is not found because it's not in the global scope.
- To fix this issue, you need to make the handleSetPassAndTicketWithDB function global. You can do this by attaching the function to the window object in your sample.js file.

  ```
  window.handleSetPassAndTicketWithDB = async () => {
    var decryptkey = getKeyForEncryptAndDecrypt('9953425561');
    var myIndexDB = IndexDB(objectStoreKeys.myPassHistory);
    let pass = await myIndexDB.get('twqwa', decryptkey);
    var divElement = document.getElementById('updateMe');
    if (divElement) {
       divElement.innerHTML = 'IndexedDB updated with key: ' + JSON.stringify(pass);
    }
    return pass;
  };
  ```
- The IndexDB function is not defined in your sample.js file. You need to define it before using it.

  ```
  window.IndexDB = async (objectStoreKey) => {
    const dbName = 'myDatabase';
    const dbVersion = 1;
    const dbRequest = indexedDB.open(dbName, dbVersion);

    dbRequest.onupgradeneeded = (event) => {
        const db = event.target.result;
        if (!db.objectStoreNames.contains(objectStoreKey)) {
            db.createObjectStore(objectStoreKey);
        }
    };

    const db = await dbRequest;

    return {
        get: async (key, decryptkey) => {
            const transaction = db.transaction(objectStoreKey, 'readonly');
            const objectStore = transaction.objectStore(objectStoreKey);
            const request = objectStore.get(key);
            const result = await request;
            if (result) {
                const decrypted = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(result, decryptkey);
                return decrypted.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8);
            }
            return null;
        },
    };
  };
  ```